# Quantile Forest error "predict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quantiles'"

Tags: python, quantile, quantile-regression

I continue to run into errors when run any form of quantile forest models with the prediction and quantile phases. I am following this example but with my own X and y. I have trained many a random forest and other derivations of tree models with this dataset, so I'm fairly certain it's not the input data issue.

https://github.com/zillow/quantile-forest

And have created an environment that supposedly follows all the installation requirements. I can provide my list of versions upon request. Time and time again, the `RandomForestQuantileRegressor` will work, but when I want to plot and see the quantiles, I get the error

> **"TypeError: predict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quantiles'"
> **

Here is an example when I set up the environment:

> Collecting quantile-forest
> Downloading quantile_forest-1.1.2-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (188 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 188.6/188.6 kB 2.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.23 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/uq_rf/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from quantile-forest) (1.24.3)
> Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.4 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/uq_rf/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from quantile-forest) (1.10.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=1.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/uq_rf/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from quantile-forest) (1.2.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.1.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/uq_rf/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scikit-learn>=1.0->quantile-forest) (1.2.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/uq_rf/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scikit-learn>=1.0->quantile-forest) (3.1.0)
> Installing collected packages: quantile-forest
> Successfully installed quantile-forest-1.1.2

This code works:

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, train_size=0.5, random_state=0)

qrf = RandomForestQuantileRegressor(q=[0.05, 0.50, 0.95])
qrf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred_5, y_pred_median, y_pred_95 = qrf.predict(X_test)
qrf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

But I cannot get any code that calls "predict" where I specify the quantiles to work without that type error.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the code you've provided is an example from the [sklearn-quantile](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn-quantile/) package. Perhaps confusingly, both packages -- sklearn-quantile and quantile-forest -- provide a `RandomForestQuantileRegressor` class, but the packages have different ways of passing the quantiles to the class methods. As a result, the `RandomForestQuantileRegressor` classes from the two packages are not currently interchangeable.

In the code snippet you've provided, it's not clear what imports are being used, but it appears that you may be using the `RandomForestQuantileRegressor` class from the sklearn-quantile package. This class expects the quantiles to be passed to the initialization function instead of the predict function and would lead to the error you've presented. If this is correct, then you can fix this by importing the `RandomForestQuantileRegressor` class from the quantile-forest package and passing the quantiles to the predict function instead of the initialization function.

If the above is not helpful or you still are running into errors, you're welcome to create an issue in the quantile-forest repository [here](https://github.com/zillow/quantile-forest/issues) for additional troubleshooting.